# Error with manually linked React Native Package

Tags: react-native, npm

Every time I run `react-native run-android` I get the following error:

```
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
  - react-native-image-picker (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-image-picker")
```

And then after I run the following command:
`react-native unlink react-native-image-picker`, I still get the same error.

I deleted node_modules and ran `npm i` and still am getting the same error.

Do you all have any suggestions?

I am on `Windows 10`

Comment: Which version of react native you have used???

Answer (score 1):

The following code maybe helps you.

```
npm unlink react-native-image-picker
```

Comment: This didn't resolve this issue. Thank you though! This is such a weird thing!

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually unlink project in following files:

`settings.gradle`
`MainApplication.java`
`app/build.gradle`

Also be aware to remove project imports in `MainApplication.java` file and remove packages from `List<ReactPackage>`, Your `getPackages` method should be like this:

```
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
  List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
  // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
  // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());

  return packages;
}
```

Or use `react-native unlink react-native-image-picker` and then clean your project and build it again.